# VirtualDocumentRoot works well but does not make any change to $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]

Tags: php, apache, config

I use VirtualDocumentRoot directive for dynamice virtual hosts on apache,
now my virtualhosts are working well
but wen I check the value of  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]
it still have the value of first DocumentRoot definition
not VirtualDocumentRoot value !

the brief part of my "http.conf" file is:

```
UseCanonicalName Off
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost

    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/vhosts/%0"

    ErrorLog "logs/dynamic-vhosts-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dynamic-vhosts-access.log" combined

</VirtualHost>
```

when I run this php code bellow

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
?>
```

I get /var/www/html as result.
If I comment this line

```
#DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

the PHP result would be

```
/etc/httpd/htdocs
```

But I want the value of $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] be like this:

```
/var/vhosts/exampleDomain.com
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Which version of Apache? [This issue should be fixed since 2.4.1](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26052).

Comment: Thank you.

Yes, this bug was fixed in Apache v2.4.1,
I cannot install Apache 2.4.x with PHP 5.6.x on CentOS 6.5 !
Thats why I forced to use Apache2.2 :(


Now I'm seeking a solution to have httpd 2.4 and php 5.6 together...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see http://joshbenner.me/blog/quick-tip-get-proper-document-root-when-using-mod-vhost-alias/

> I found a great solution to this in the related apache bug report: Simply add the following line to your apache configuration inside the VirtualDocumentRoot vhost definition:
>
> `php_admin_value auto_prepend_file /path/setdocroot.php`
>
> Then, create the referenced PHP file, and put set this as its contents:
>
> `<?php
> $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = str_replace($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);`
>
> Now, every page load has this file executed, which properly sets DOCUMENT_ROOT.